# Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). When using functional api for CNN LSTM

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to do a simple cnn-lstm classification with time distributed but I am getting the following error:
**Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found:**

my samples are grayscaled images of 366 channels and 5x5 size each sample has its own unique label.

```
model_input = Input(shape=(366,5,5))

model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format='channels_first')(model_input))
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))

model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu',padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))


model = Flatten()

model = LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5)
model =  Dense(128, activation='relu')


model = Dense(6, activation='softmax')

cnnlstm = Model(model_input, model)
cnnlstm.compile(optimizer='adamax',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
cnnlstm.summary()
```

Comment: Did you read the Functional API guide? Because the code is kind of completely wrong, you are not passing the tensors between layers, you are doing it correctly only in the first TimeDistributed layer

Comment: Thanks. I have to say am still new to this. But to my understanding with timedistributed wrapper the tensor is only needed for the first layer.

Comment: No, that understanding is incorrect.

Comment: I tried update the code, but when passing the flatten output to the lstm layer as in  : 
model = TimeDistributed(Flatten())

model = LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5)(model)  I am getting an error:  **Layer lstm_48 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.**

Comment: Again you are not passing the tensor to the layer (the timedistributed flatten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass tensors between the layers as this is how the Functional API works, for all layers, using the `Layer(params...)(input)` notation:

```
model_input = Input(shape=(366,5,5))

model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))(model_input)
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))(model)

model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu',padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'))(model)


model = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(model)

model = LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5)(model)
model =  Dense(128, activation='relu')(model)


model = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(model)

cnnlstm = Model(model_input, model)
```

Note that I have also corrected the first `TimeDistributed` layer, as the tensor was in the wrong part.

Comment: Thank you Matias. But running the code above I am getting  an error: **Dimension must be 3 but is 4 for 'time_distributed_304/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,5,5], [4].**  my input shape seems correct 366 channels 5*5. Dont know what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much Matias, you saved me tone of hours. It's working fine now. The problem was with my input shape, I did not specify the number of channels for each single time steps which in my case is 1. So, model_input = Input(shape=(366,1,5,5)) fixed the issue. Now my accuracy is not changing I hope to fix it.